# Embed a GeoTools map in an existing Java Swing application

Tags: java, geotools

I have a Java GUI Swing application with three frames. I want to load a map from a shapefile and draw the map on an existing application frame. For this I use [GeoTools](http://www.geotools.org/) framework. I've looked at the examples and all examples have drawn the map on a separate GUI window `JMapFrame`.

(I've followed this link http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/quickstart/netbeans.html)

Is there a way which we can embed a map that we have created using Geotools to an existing Java Swing application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use a [`JMapPane`](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/master/modules/unsupported/swing/src/main/java/org/geotools/swing/JMapPane.java) - for the most part I would look at the code for [`JMapFrame`](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/master/modules/unsupported/swing/src/main/java/org/geotools/swing/JMapFrame.java) and cherry pick the parts I needed in my application.

Comment: Thanks. I'm currently working on what you suggested. In the mean time, my end application would need features like adding new lines, nodes to the map, selecting a line/node on the map and displaying properties of that selected part and drawing names/values on the map. (Eg: population of a city). I'm curious whether JMapPane is the answer for this as the document says JMapPane is just for demo purpose, but not intended for Desktop GIS apps. Please comment on this.

Comment: JMapPane just draws maps, it's up to you to add other UI widgets etc to provide the functions you need.